# phonega-plugin-push don't work in backgrond in Android Oreo

Tags: ionic-framework, android-8.0-oreo, phonegap-plugin-push

I'm using ionic 1 and the plugin, phonegap-plugin-push version 2.1.0. the app works correctly on Android 7 and earlier, but in Android 8 this not work in background, I just recive in foreground